# Bootstrap progress bar disappears when floated

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the bootstrap bar to show the progress of a song. When I add it to a list stylize it to float, it disappears.

```css
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li {
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
        <div class="text-muted" id="currentTime"></div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="progress" style="width: 10%;">
            <div id="progressBar" class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" style="width: 0%" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="text-muted" id="totalTime"></div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: do you have a url we can look at? Ideally we need to see how the parent divs above your ul is structured. Also, its advisable to encapsulate your classes so they dont override each other which is possibly the issue here

Comment: @idlab Here you go: https://taromaru.ml/a/playlist/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Applying the float property causes the elements to lose their dimensions (especially the width).

[`ّfloat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) explained in MDN Web Docs:

> When an element is floated, it is taken out of the normal flow of the
> document (though still remaining part of it). It is shifted to the
> left, or right, until it touches the edge of its containing box, or
> another floated element.

You can cover this problem by applying the parent width at the same time.

```
li {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Do not forget to use Bootstrap classes. (e.g. `w-100`, `float-left`, `m-0`, `p-0`, `overflow-hidden`, ... )